# Should I file a pull request or merge when updating branches on a single developer GitHub project?

Tags: git, github, merge, branch, pull-request

I'm using GitHub Desktop to manage my GitHub repository. It's a project with multiple branches (I'm using [this model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)), and I'm in a situation where I sometimes want to have updates made in one branch present in another.

In my particular situation I've got a develop branch and a feature branch I created from develop for a particular addon. This addon is dependant upon elements being updated in develop, and recently I fixed a bug in develop which I wanted to get over to the feature branch too.

There seems to be two ways to do this (approached from a GUI perspective):

1. Raise a pull request
2. Run a merge (specifically I switch to the branch I want to update in GitHub desktop, do a comparison with the branch you want to update from and click the merge from button)

My question is: what's the difference? I've been favouring merges for this sort of thing simply because if a pull request creates conflicts it seems to take several more steps to resolve them than it does with a merge. So to my eyes the two do pretty much the same thing, but I feel there must be more to it. Are pull requests designed for when you don't have the permissions to merge yourself? For when another developer needs to sign-off? For when you want to file the request but not tackle the conflicts there and then? Something else? The documentation on this I've seen explained the working but not the purpose, at least not in a way that left me any clearer on this.

For a single developer project is there a reason to use a pull request over a merge? Is there some fundamental difference between the two that I'm missing?

Apologies if the terminology is a little off, I'm fairly new to the whole branching thing and am trying to come at this from a git best practice perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pull Requests are meant to collaborate over a set of changes. If you're working on a project by yourself, then merging makes more sense.

From the GitHub [Pull Request documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/):

> Pull requests let you tell others about changes you've pushed to a repository on GitHub. Once a pull request is sent, interested parties can review the set of changes, discuss potential modifications, and even push follow-up commits if necessary.